# Remove italic text from footer but not ToC

Tags: italic, small-caps, footer

Since I have some italic text in some subsections, when I place the section mark in small caps in the footer, the text in italic remains lower case. How can I remove the \textit setting exclusively in the footer (I tried with the short section name, i.e. \section[short name]{long name} but this way the italic text is also removed from the ToC, which I don't want)?

Reference code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\begin{document}
...
\tableofcontents
...
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\sc{\leftmark}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection \space #1}{}}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\sc{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{Chapter \thechapter: #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}

\chapter{Chapter name}
\thispagestyle{plain}
\section{bla bla \textit{bla} bla}

\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you @Zarko!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a font that has italic (or slanted) small caps; the `cfr-lm` package provides Latin Modern with the requested feature and many more.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[
  rm={lining=true,tabular=true},
  sf={lining=true,tabular=true},
  tt={lining=true,tabular=true},
]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancypagestyle{standard}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
  \fancyfoot[LO]{\nouppercase{\textsc{\leftmark}}}%
  \fancyfoot[RE]{\nouppercase{\textsc{\rightmark}}}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
%  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}
\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{Chapter \thechapter: #1}{}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\thesection \space #1}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
%  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}%
}

\pagestyle{standard}

\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter name}

\section{Bla bla \textit{bla} bla}

\clearpage

abc

\clearpage

def

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked wonderfully!

Answer (score 0):

In the `memoir` class (a superset of `book` and `report` classes) sectional divisions (from `\book` to `\subparagraph`) can have two optional arguments:

```
\section[<toc-title>][<head-title>]{<title>}
\subsection[<toc-title>][<head-title>}{<title>}
```

and so on. This enables you to have different titles in the ToC, the header, and the main document, where the words and/or fonts can be different.